# LINQ to Entities: Using DateTime.AddMonth in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've been reading some posts but I don't find a solution to a problem that I have with LINQ To Entities, Lambda Expressions and `DateTime.AddMonth`.

The problem is that I'm trying to use `DateTime.AddMonth` inside a Lambda Expression and I'm getting this error:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression"

when I execute this piece of code:

```
List<Orders> orders = context.Orders
                        .Where(o => o.IdOrderStatus == 1)
                        .Where(o => o.PaymentDate.Value.AddMonths(o.Products.ProductCategories.CommissionableMonths) > DateTime.Now)
                        .ToList();
```

Is there a way to avoid this exception but mantaining the same behavior?

I don't know a lot about Linq, Lambdas or Entity Framework.

Thank you very much in advance!

Gsus.

Comment: Is o.Products.ProductCategories.Commissionable and Int32 value of the number of months you want to add to PaymentDate?

Comment: You should tag this question Linq and C#

Comment: @jvanderh: Yes, is the number of months I want to add to the payment date.

@jvanderh: I'll tag it as Liqn and C#

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could return the necessary information without filtering on the date, then filter on the date afterward.  (Of course, I'm not sure what size your data will be, so this may be inefficient.  If so, you'll need a SQL-based solution of some sort -- maybe a stored procedure.)

```
List<Orders> orders = context.Orders
                        .Where(o => o.IdOrderStatus == 1)
                        .ToList();
orders = orders.Where(o.PaymentDate.Value.AddMonths(o.Products.ProductCategories.CommissionableMonths) > DateTime.Now);
```

This turns the AddMonths portion of the query in to a Linq-to-Objects method instead of Linq-to-Entities call.

Comment: Thanks John.

The PaymentDate is one of the big filters we need to get a small amount of data, so we will use a stored procedure to solve this issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
var today =DateTime.Now;
List<Orders> orders = context.Orders
                    .Where(o => o.IdOrderStatus == 1)
                    .Where(o => SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month"   ,o.Products.ProductCategories.CommissionableMonths,o.PaymentDate) > today)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities converts your linq expression into SQL code, sometimes this conversion is seamless such as integer addition, selects, groups, etc, but sometimes the abstraction leaks, as in date operations.